# PDF reader for OpenBSD that has default disabled JAVA/JavaScript/etc.?

Tags: openbsd

I'm searching for a PDF reader that doesn't supports Java, JavaScript in PDF files (and other unneeded things what is only used in 1% of the PDF files, but can cause security issues). Or there isn't any?

Answer (score 3):

OpenBSD 6.2 has at least these PDF viewers in ports:

- `x11/gnustep/gspdf`: "GSPdf is a PDF and PostScript file viewer for GNUstep."
- `textproc/xpdf`: "Xpdf is an open source viewer for Portable Document Format (PDF) files."
- `textproc/pdfpc`: "pdfpc is a GTK-based presentation viewer which uses Keynote-like
  multi-monitor output to provide meta information to the speaker during
  the presentation."
- `textproc/mupdf`: "MuPDF is a lightweight PDF and XPS viewer."
- `productivity/impressive`: "Impressive is a program that displays PDF presentation slides with
  style."
- `print/gv`: "GNU gv allows to view and navigate through PostScript and PDF documents
  on an X display by providing a user interface for the ghostscript
  interpreter."
- `print/apvlv`: "Apvlv is a PDF Viewer with vim-like keybindings."

Out of these, I have only ever used `xpdf` and `gv`, and neither use Java or JavaScript as far as I know.

The above list was compiled by looking for the word `PDF` in the port description files on a system with the `/usr/ports` hierarchy checked out form CVS:

```
find /usr/ports/ -type f -name 'DESCR*' -exec grep -iF pdf {} +
```

See also [the OpenBSD Package Management FAQ](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq15.html).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:

- [Alternatives to evince](http://alternativeto.net/software/evince/?platform=linux) (evince itself is quite good)
- [Zathura](http://pwmt.org/projects/zathura/) (uses poppler or mupdf backend)
- [FireFox's pdf.js](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/pdfjs/) - not sure if this supports js itself - but I doubt it does for now